# Why is my code resulting in a segmentation fault but not with a different starting parameter?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I am translating a C program into Assembly. I have a particular problem translating one of the helper functions. The function works in C. When I try testing it in Assembly I get a segmentation fault if the stack_size is 0 at the beginning but when it is 1 then the segmentation fault no longer appears.

C function:

```
void addToStack(long *stack, int *stacksize, int number) {
(*stacksize)++;    
stack[*stacksize-1] = number;
}
```

Note that stack is an array of long. Stack size is not actually the size of the array, but the number of elements set inside. For example, a new array should have stack_size=0 and if we put a number in the array we should put in position stack_size and then increment stack_size.

This is the implementation of the code in NASM using AT&T syntax:

```
//addToStack function
.globl addToStack
addToStack:
//Stack pointer is %rdi
//Stack size pointer is %rsi
//Number (to add) is %rdx

//Get stack size
movq (%rsi), %r8
//Get size of stack in bytes
imul $8, %r8
//Add size of stack to stack pointer (to move it)
add %r8, %rdi
//Put number in memory at rdi
movq %rdx, (%rdi)
//Get stack size
movq (%rsi), %r9
//Increment stack size
add $1, %r9
//Put new size in size pointer memory
movq %r9, (%rsi)

ret
```

This is the test:

```
//Tests addToStack function
void testAddToStack(TestObjs *obj) {
int stack_size = 0;
long myStack[5];
memset(myStack, 0, 5*sizeof(long));

addToStack(myStack, &stack_size, 1);
ASSERT(stack_size == 1);
ASSERT(myStack[1] == 1); 

addToStack(myStack, &stack_size, 2);

addToStack(myStack, &stack_size, 3);
addToStack(myStack, &stack_size, 4);
addToStack(myStack, &stack_size, 5);
ASSERT(stack_size == 5);
ASSERT(myStack[1] == 2); 
ASSERT(myStack[2] == 3);
ASSERT(myStack[3] == 4);
ASSERT(myStack[4] == 5);   
}
```

If you change the stack_size in the test function to 1 instead of 0 then there won't be a segmentation fault. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stack_size` is an `int` (32 bits) but you use it as 64 bit. PS: learn to use a debugger. PS #2: that's quite inefficient code.

Comment: NASM doesn't understand AT&T syntax.  Presumably you're assembling it with GAS.

Comment: @Jester how can I improve my code? The GDB debugger doesn’t let me go through the assembly code one line at a time

Comment: It does, you used it wrong. See `(gdb) help stepi`.